# How can I export a JavaScript literal in React.NET

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am using properties to pass in component dependencies. This is especially important when doing server-side rendering, with code that depends on run-time libraries like jQuery or SignalR. In my case, I need to render my component server-side then have JS hook up to it and stream real-time data in the browser. So I don't need SignalR server-side, but I need to pass in a reference to a web socket hub on the client using React.NET.

```
@Html.React("Comments", new
{
    data = Model,
    conn = "$.hubConnection()" //<--- I need this to be a literal not a string
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the source code of React.NET I found that it uses `Newtonsoft` to serialize the data. So you can use `JRaw`.

```
@Html.React("Comments", new
{
    data = Model,
    conn = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw("$.hubConnection()")
})
```

Then I just needed to include a simple mock so that it wouldn't throw errors during server-side rendering.

```
// this file contains mocks for global variables that are referenced by server-side code but only needed client-side. For example SignalR.

// mock jQuery
var $ = jQuery = {};

// mock SignalR API
$.hubConnection = function() {};
```

Works like a charm!